# Read Networkstream for HTTP-Request

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I havent found anything related to this topic, so i ask you.

What I am trying to acchieve is process a NetowrkStream from a Socket.

It does contain a HTTPWebRequest from a WebShop. Soap, to be more specific.

What I want to avoid is using a StreamReader and read line by line. Is there a standart class I can use for this? (Or how do I convert the stream into a WebRequest?)

For example theese are the first lines of the Stream:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2006 15:12:48 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Jan 2006 11:18:20 GMT
Content-Language: de
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Networkstream is created like this :

```
using (NetworkStream netowrkStream = new NetworkStream(_socket))
{
    if (netowrkStream.CanRead)
    { 
         // PSEUDO: HttpRequest = HttpRequest.FromStream(networkStream);
```

**Trying to ask more simple:**

What is considered the best way to retrieve a HTTP-Request from a network stream and parse its data?

Comment: Suppose some code you have already for this would be good here.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that? All I have is a Network Stream delivering a HTTP-Requestheader with  following XML-Data. I was hopind it is possible to pass the Stream to the HHTPListener-Class or anything similiar.

Comment: Implementing HTTP with `Sockets` is hard and has already been done for you in the framework in the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) class - I suggest you use that if you can.

Comment: That looks like a web response, not a web request.

Comment: @NicholasButler thats what i was searching for. thank you.

Comment: @CSharpie Great! I've added my comment as an answer so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implementation of an HTTP server in the framework:

[MSDN: System.Net.HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

I suggest you use that if you can.